# Target properties for python module

Tags: python, cmake

What properties can I set for a target added with `python_add_module` in CMake.

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.14.5
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What kind of property are you trying to set, or what are you trying to accomplish? The `python_add_module` command actually calls `add_library` with the `STATIC` or `MODULE` clause, depending on your configuration. So you can set any of [these](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets) target properties...

Comment: This clarifies my question

Comment: Ok, I added a link to the CMake source in my answer so you can see how `python_add_module()` is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python_add_module` command actually calls `add_library()` with the `STATIC` or `MODULE` clause, depending on your configuration. See the CMake source [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake#L317). So you can set any of [these](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets) target properties for targets create via `python_add_module`.